# Save Excel File with Current Date Time in File Name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to save an output of a pandas df to an excel file.  I'd like to include the date and time within the file name as well as an instance of the data frame itself.

Here's the code I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'Apple' : ['iPhone', 'iPad', 'Mac']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
filename = df.iloc[1]

e = datetime.datetime.now()
print(filename, e,'.xlsx')
df.to_excel(print(filename,e,'.xlsx'),index=False)
#this errors out
```

Expected output would be the string `iPad_[The Current Date and Time].xlsx` and ability to save the file as an excel file.  The iPad is coming from the `filename` variable and the current date and time is coming from the `e` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should save excel file with:

```
filename = df.iloc[1,0]
e = datetime.datetime.now()
df.to_excel(f"{filename}{e}.xlsx", index=False)
```